# Responsive CSS grid images are overlapping

Tags: css, grid, responsive

I've got a tarot card application that displays the back of a set of cards, then when you click on the card, which is a button the card flips over. The main issue I have is a set it up with a set of images for the front and back ~200x276. The CSS I have seems fine other than some minor alignment when the card is "flipped". My major issue is that I've used a larger set of images and now the cards overlap. How do I setup my grid to automatically adjust for the different sizes of the card sets images? My CSS skill is beginner level.

CSS

```
.btn-default
{
    border: none;
    background: none;
    display: inline-block;
  height: 180px;
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 0;
}

.btn-default:hover {
    background: none;
}

.card-oracle-cards {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: .5rem;
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
    padding: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.card-oracle-card {
    perspective: 300px;
    width: auto;
    height: 180px;
}

.card-oracle-card-body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

.card-oracle-card-body.is-flipped {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}

.card-oracle-back,
.card-oracle-front,
.card-oracle-front-reverse {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.card-oracle-front,
.card-oracle-front-reverse {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-oracle-front-reverse {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.card-oracle-back:hover {
    background: white;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */
}
.card-oracle-img-btn
{
    background: none;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.card-oracle-rotate-image {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="card-oracle-cards">
  <div class="card-oracle-card">
    <div class="card-oracle-card-body">
      <div class="card-oracle-back"><button type="button" value="1359" id="id1359" data-value="1359" onclick="this.disabled = true;" class="btn btn-default clicked"><img width="155" height="300" src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/demo_card_back-155x300.png" class="attachment-medium size-medium wp-post-image" alt="Past &#8211; Present &#8211; Future (Demo)" srcset="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/demo_card_back-155x300.png 155w, https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/demo_card_back.png 320w" sizes="(max-width: 155px) 100vw, 155px" /></button></div>
      <div class="card-oracle-front-reverse"><img width="320" height="620" src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/major01-4.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="The Magician" srcset="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/major01-4.jpg 320w, https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/major01-4-155x300.jpg 155w" sizes="(max-width: 320px) 100vw, 320px" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-oracle-card">
    <div class="card-oracle-card-body">
      <div class="card-oracle-back"><button type="button" value="1454" id="id1454" onclick="this.disabled = true;" class="btn btn-default clicked"><img width="155" height="300" src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/demo_card_back-155x300.png" class="attachment-medium size-medium wp-post-image" alt="Past &#8211; Present &#8211; Future (Demo)" srcset="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/demo_card_back-155x300.png 155w, https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/demo_card_back.png 320w" sizes="(max-width: 155px) 100vw, 155px" /></button></div>
      <div class="card-oracle-front"><img width="320" height="620" src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/major20-4.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Judgement" srcset="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/major20-4.jpg 320w, https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/major20-4-155x300.jpg 155w" sizes="(max-width: 320px) 100vw, 320px" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-oracle-card">
    <div class="card-oracle-card-body">
      <div class="card-oracle-back"><button type="button" value="1404" id="id1404" onclick="this.disabled = true;" class="btn btn-default clicked"><img width="155" height="300" src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/demo_card_back-155x300.png" class="attachment-medium size-medium wp-post-image" alt="Past &#8211; Present &#8211; Future (Demo)" srcset="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/demo_card_back-155x300.png 155w, https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/demo_card_back.png 320w" sizes="(max-width: 155px) 100vw, 155px" /></button></div>
      <div class="card-oracle-front"><img width="320" height="620" src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/major10-4.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Wheel of Fortune" srcset="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/major10-4.jpg 320w, https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/major10-4-155x300.jpg 155w" sizes="(max-width: 320px) 100vw, 320px" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-oracle-card">
    <div class="card-oracle-card-body">
      <div class="card-oracle-back"><button type="button" value="1374" id="id1374" data-value="1374" onclick="this.disabled = true;" class="btn btn-default clicked"><img width="155" height="300" src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/demo_card_back-155x300.png" class="attachment-medium size-medium wp-post-image" alt="Past &#8211; Present &#8211; Future (Demo)" srcset="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/demo_card_back-155x300.png 155w, https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/demo_card_back.png 320w" sizes="(max-width: 155px) 100vw, 155px" /></button></div>
      <div class="card-oracle-front-reverse"><img width="320" height="620" src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/major04-4.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="The Emperor" srcset="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/major04-4.jpg 320w, https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/major04-4-155x300.jpg 155w" sizes="(max-width: 320px) 100vw, 320px" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-oracle-card">
    <div class="card-oracle-card-body">
      <div class="card-oracle-back"><button type="button" value="1389" id="id1389" onclick="this.disabled = true;" class="btn btn-default clicked"><img width="155" height="300" src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/demo_card_back-155x300.png" class="attachment-medium size-medium wp-post-image" alt="Past &#8211; Present &#8211; Future (Demo)" srcset="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/demo_card_back-155x300.png 155w, https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/demo_card_back.png 320w" sizes="(max-width: 155px) 100vw, 155px" /></button></div>
      <div class="card-oracle-front"><img width="320" height="620" src="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/major07-4.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="The Chariot" srcset="https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/major07-4.jpg 320w, https://cuspstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/major07-4-155x300.jpg 155w" sizes="(max-width: 320px) 100vw, 320px" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've done an example on codepen, https://codepen.io/chillichalli/pen/oNbyzRN

[image: Small set, that look correct]

[image: Overlapping images]

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check: "display:grid" only applies to direct children. You have divs with the class "card-oracle-cards" nested inside one another. That might be causing some problems. Try reassigning some div classes.

Comment: Thanks I did not know that. I've tried to remove the card-oracle-card div but now all the rows are stacked on top of each other.

Comment: I'm not great with CSS--bit if a beginner myself. I do think using grid is the way to go. There is a good resource here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/